# How to detect whether postgresql database is corrupted?

Tags: postgresql, backup, corrupt

Referring to the official documentation, I now find that there are two ways:

1. set param zero_damaged_pages on, However, it is not recommended because data loss may occur, and I do not Know if the database is corrupt;
2. set checksum on, This can cause significant performance costs, and You can find the database is corrupted when you query

I want to restore data using a backup database when find current database is corrupted on embedded device. Is there  more convenient way to find out whether postgresql database is corrupt just like sqlite? In sqlite, Database corruption can be detected by the API return value:

#define SQLITE_CORRUPT     11   /* The database disk image is malformed */

Comment: Postgresql or SQLite? They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways won't reliably detect all kinds of data corruption. `zero_damaged_pages` won't help at all, and checksums will only detect data corruption on disk (as opposed to corruption in RAM or caused by database bugs).

Some data corruption can be detected by nasty error messages, for example if you dump the database (which selects all data). Other types of data corruption causes no errors, but bad results.